# Vector class in Flex SDK

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, actionscript, air

From which version of the Flex SDK is the Vector class available for Adobe AIR applications? I want to use a library that contains some code with Vectors. But my Flex Builder 3 (Flex SDK 3.0) doesnt seem to support it.

Comment: imho flex 4, _Runtime Versions:  Flash Player 10, AIR 1.5, Flash Lite 4_

Comment: Ok thank you. But doesnt SDK 3.0.2 add support to FP 10? any way i am going to try SDK 3.2 from my friend and see if it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use any version above SDK v3.2 but you will have to make some changes in the project in order to [target the Flash Player 10](http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/display/flexsdk/Targeting+Flash+Player+10).

Answer (score 0):

Try to open project properties>Flex Compiler>Adobe Flash Player Options and set version of the Flash Player as 10.0.0.

Comment: I am building an AIR application. I guess thats why i dont see an option called Adobe Flash Player.